# How to measure the bonding wire inductance in lab by myself?

Tags: pcb, integrated-circuit, pcb-design, inductor

Very curious about the IC design. Everytime when we get our chips , we always need to bond wire the chip to connect the PCB. Even though the factory always claims that the bonding wire is 0.8nH/mm for inductance model, then I am still very curious, ***how to measure the bonding wire inductance value by myself in lab for practical situation***?

Does any expert know how to do it ? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

A dedicated LCR or Qmeter will allow you to measure this directly, however, my guess is you don't have access to one otherwise you would have used it already. A Vector Network Analyzer would also work by monitoring changes in the Smith Chart.

For regular inductors this is done with a function gen and a scope like so ([link](http://www.dos4ever.com/inductor/inductor.html)).

Something in the nH range may not be feasible with the above method...if you have access to a VHF scanning receiver a method like this will work ([link](http://www.rfcafe.com/forums/systems/to%20measure%20nanohenry%20inductors.htm)).

Comment: I'm not the OP. But on the IC's I've seen that were direct attached to the PCB, the bonding pads were pretty small. Hard to imagine probing the bonding pad with the LCR meter, unless an additional wire lead was introduced. Seems like that would throw off the measurement by adding more inductance. Would love to hear any comments.

Comment: @mkeith There exist precision probes for silicone dies like here (http://www.tezzaron.com/media/wafer.jpg). However, I assume you would have to get a sample of the bond wire and test it in some kind of jig. With measurements this precise I doubt any in-circuit measurements would be worthwhile.

Comment: @Gonzik  thanks for your answer.   I dont have these equipments as you guessed. I am just wondering by simple facility is it possible to measure it. but for your answer seems its very hard to measure by hand.. can you tell me more about the vector network analyzer method ? is it small enough to be used as a probe for the bonding wire... confused...

Comment: @Gonzik  sorry to bother you again, I have a question about how to use the vector network analyzer to measure the inductance. As I know, the aligent N5227A VNA, I can measure the S parameter and monitor the change of smith chart, but if I get the S parameter, how can I exact inductance value from the S paramter ?　does equation Z=50* (1+S11)/(1-S11) work ? feel confused...

Answer (score 0):

I think the only practical way to do this would be to construct a special test chip that has two pads near a corner that are shorted to each other. Attach a bond wire to each pad, making sure that they run at right angles to each other in order to minimize mutual coupling. Measure the inductance of this setup and then divide by two.

Answer (score 0):

How about a theory number?  The "Radio Engineer's Handbook by Terman, lists inductance for straight round wires.  There are corrections for the skin effect at higher frequencies.